# Can't terminate gunicorn_django via Ctrl-C when invoked from a makefile

Tags: django, macos, makefile, gunicorn

I have a very simple makefile for launching my Django app using gunicorn:

```
run:
    gunicorn_django
```

If I launch gunicorn using this makefile, then I cannot terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. However, if I just type `gunicorn_django` at the bash prompt, then I am able to terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Why would this be?

(Note: I'm running on OS X Lion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this bug can be found [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/356).